# Definition of non-monotonic sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, definition, quantifiers

I am working on other proofs, namely for so-called "quasi-increasing" but non-monotonic sequences.

But, my question: is the following a sufficient definition of non-monotonic?

> For all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where $l>n>m \ge N$ there is $a_n \le a_m$ and $a_l \ge a_n$

Namely, there are always terms with preceding and following terms both greater.

I am not sure if the quantification is correct, as in I do not want to say each element has all elements before and after it greater. This would seem contradictory to me, and misses the idea of mere non-monotonicity.

Comment: Something like "there is an $n$ such that $a_{n-1} < a_n > a_{n+1}$".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Excuse me, there was a typo. I believe what I have said is equivalent to what you have said there is $a_l \ge a_n \le a_m$ and for $l>n>m \ge N$ is satsified by $a_{n-1} < a_n > a_{n+1}$ for $l=n+1>n=n>m=n-1$. Thank you. Is it just that I can remove the "for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negate the definition:

$\exists m,n, p, q \in\mathbb{N}$ s.t ($ n>m $ but $x_n<x_m$) and ($p>q$ but $x_p >x_q$)

Comment: Thank you. How is this different from the definition I gave? Is it that I need not specify for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes I think the for all N is actually wrong, because if you use the non-monotonic sequence $x_n= 1/n$ for n=1,2 and $x_n=n$ otherwise, then it's not true for all N that you can find numbers to the right which are not part of a strictly increasing sequence, which is what the definition currently suggests.

Comment: In fact, as your definition stands right now above, it is not properly quantified and so is confusing: It is hard to understand what is meant by l,n,m. Definitions like these should use for all, there exists etc. so we can understand what they mean in the context of the definition.